# Why are the options given for IconData causing errors when used?

Tags: warning-messages, options

> Reported to Wolfram Technical Support [CASE:4212712]

---

Using [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) on `IconData` reveals:

```
Options @ IconData

(* {Background → None, ImageSize → Automatic} *)
```

Great! Let's simply use them:

```
IconData[ "WindDirection", 315, Background -> None ]
```

[image: error]

**Why are we getting an unknown option error (OptionValue)? Is something similar also observable for other built-in functions?**

Note: This will also happen for `ImageSize`.
I am using Version 11.3 on Windows 10 (64 Bit).

**Update:**

While we may argue about the above -- after all the documentation for [`IconData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IconData.html) will not show valid options --, note the following behavior:

```
SetOptions[ IconData, Background → Green];
IconData["WindDirection", 315]
```

You will note, that the options indeed have changed, but now there is no green background, while

```
IconData["WindDirection", 315, Background -> Green]
```

will show a green background albeit throwing an error message as given above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88294/discussion-on-question-by-gwr-why-are-the-options-given-for-icondata-causing-err).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my comment, if you look at `InputForm@IconData["WindDirection", 315]`, you'll see that it returns a `Graphics` object.

Thus a sensible workaround would be:

```
Show[IconData["WindDirection", 315], Background -> Green]
```

since it will act like any other `Graphics` object.

For instance, you would also be able to use `DiscretizeGraphics` and its ilk:

[image: discretize example]

The natural Wolfram order of things is that if a symbol or something about a symbol is not documented, it's not officially supported and is likely to change, stop working, or exhibit weird behaviour (as in your case).

Comment: And yet, we are not spelunking, but simply checking for options, which are given but do not work as options should...

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you that they exist and should work; I'm just stating that it's not terribly surprising that they don't, given that they're undocumented.

Answer (score 4):

From the above comments and some inspection we find that according to the decisive authority of the documentation using `Options` for `IconData` is not supported. Using `Trace` we see that `IconData` uses `` DataPaclets`IconDataDump` `` which will not make use of the options given in a way we want.

One work around is to use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) for the `Graphics` object returned by `IconData` (a careful inspection using `FullForm` will tell you what to replace):

```
IconData["WindDirection", 315] // ReplaceAll@
    {
        Rule[Background, None] -> Rule[Background, Green],
        Rule[ImageSize, __ ] -> Rule[ImageSize, Large]
    }
```

[image: LargeIcon]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative work-around is to take the graphics primitives returned by `IconData` and use them in `Graphics` with desired options added:

```
Graphics[First @ IconData["WindDirection", 315], 
 Background -> Green, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) But I have to admit that Carl Lange's solution as given in the comments looks simpler, e.g. `Show[ IconData["WindDirection", 315], Background -> Green, ImageSize -> Large ]`.

Comment: Thank you @gwr. I agree `Show` is more straightforward; I thought you commented that it produced the same error message in your system.

Comment: Actually my bad: I missed his bracket making `IconData` an expression within `Show` (which is why I deleted my comment ... and probably should have told @CarlLange more explicitly).